# Exception(org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component ) while running the tomcat server

Tags: tomcat10

I have deployed my application in the tomcat server(v10.1.7),when i try to start the server getting the below Exception.

06-May-2023 16:16:27.598 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
06-May-2023 16:16:27.644 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8085]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1018)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1003)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:747)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:769)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:307)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:477)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:459)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:448)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:247)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:202)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1256)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1269)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:622)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:77)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1016)
... 13 more
06-May-2023 16:16:27.672 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["https-jsse-nio-8443"]
06-May-2023 16:16:27.704 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException Failed to initialize component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-8443]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1018)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:549)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:1003)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:747)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:769)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:307)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:477)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:459)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:448)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.initServerSocket(NioEndpoint.java:247)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:202)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.bindWithCleanup(AbstractEndpoint.java:1256)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1269)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:622)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:77)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1016)
... 13 more
06-May-2023 16:16:27.727 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [1372] milliseconds
06-May-2023 16:16:27.847 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
06-May-2023 16:16:27.878 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.7]
06-May-2023 16:16:27.952 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\rfx-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
06-May-2023 16:16:28.792 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\webapps\rfx-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:975)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1949)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:776)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1656)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:140)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/rfx-web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/web/SpringServletContainerInitializer has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 55.0 (unable to load class [org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer])
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2492)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1401)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1245)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1834)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1299)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:987)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4797)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)

tried Changing the Server port number
Restarted the Tomcat server.